# Rotate text around a circle

Tags: d3.js, svg

I would like to rotate some text (numbers) that I have positioned around a circle, to appear like this:

[image]

To apply the rotation I have tried this: `.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "rotate(" + (-90 + ((360 / dial.length) * i)) + ", 135, 135)"; });` but it throws everything out.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24ma13wg/Lk01abu7/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution from @GerardoFurtado is good, but if you position everything at the origin you can simplify the code quite a bit.

Feel free to accept his answer. I just wanted to point out some efficiencies.

```js
var width = height = 300,
    circleRadius = (width / 2) * .8,
    digitRadius = (width / 2) * .9;

svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  // Everything inside the group is centred at the origin and we use
  // a transform on the group to move the whole group to the centre of the SVG
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

svg.append("circle")
  .attr("r", circleRadius)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "black");

dial = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

// Position text at X=radius, Y=0 and rotate around the origin to get final position
svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(dial)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", digitRadius)
  // tweak digit Y position a little to ensure it's centred at desired position
  .attr("y", "0.4em")
  .text(function(d, i) { return d; })
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "rotate(" + (-90 + ((360 / dial.length) * i)) + ")"; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was changing the additional values for `rotate`, where `<x>` and `<y>` values represent the coordinates of the point used as a center of rotation.:

```
rotate(<a> [<x> <y>])
```

I changed `<x>` and `<y>` for `center` and changed your `x` and `y` positions accordingly.

```js
var width = height = 300,
    radius = center = (width / 2) * .9;

svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (radius * .1) / 2 + "," + (radius * .1) / 2 + ")"; });

svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", radius)
  .attr("cy", radius)
  .attr("r", radius*.9)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "black");

// Calculate dial start and end.
dial = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(dial)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) { return center + radius * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI  / dial.length-0.75); })
  .attr("y", function(d, i) { return center + radius * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI  / dial.length-0.75); })
  .text(function(d, i) { return d; })
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "rotate(" + (-90 + ((360 / dial.length) * i)) + "," + center +  "," + center + ")"; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/24heuL1h/1/